# How to access a property value in web.xml file?

Tags: spring-mvc, struts2, web, web.xml

I Know we can't access the properties in web.xml but is there work around to achieve this.
I just have to access the value of env in web.xml file.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why? If S2 needs access to something in web.xml, it's probable it shouldn't be there in the first place.

In any case, implement [`ServletContextAware`](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/util/ServletContextAware.html) to get access to the [`ServletContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getInitParameter%28java.lang.String%29).

I'd prefer to see such things kept as constants in the S2 config file and injected, or in some other non-servlet-specific config mechanism. This also makes the action easier to test, although you can always mock the servlet context, I suppose.